# KeyCloak Server Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: java.security.acl.Group

Tags: spring-boot, keycloak, classnotfoundexception, java-11, java-14

I'm running a KeyCloak server to authenticate users who would like to gain access to a Spring Boot/Spring Web REST API. However, an error occurs while trying to authenticate.

The following works:

- When I access `http://localhost:8080/path/to/restapi`
- I get presented with a login screen as expected:
  -- [KeyCloak Login Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JQdUw.png)
- When I click login the following error occurs on the redirect from within my browser:

> Whitelabel Error Page
> This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

This is the error that's printed to the Spring Boot console:

```java
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: java.security.acl.Group
  at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:602) ~[na:na]
  at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178) ~[na:na]
  at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522) ~[na:na]
  ... 33 common frames omitted
```

The KeyCloak server shows that the session is active for the user to the application. However, the authenication process is never completed due to the above missing class.

Comment: I got the same issue but upgrading to JDK 11 did not fix it. I also downgraded to JDK 8 and that also didn't work. I also experience this issue when deploying this to a docker swarm service. Locally my Springboot service works fine. Any fix for this?

Answer (score 37):

After some research I found the answer to my problem.

The problem is that java.security.acl.Group is being deprecated since JRE 9 and marked for removal in future versions.

[java.security.acl.Group is being replaced by java.security.Policy](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/security/acl/Group.html)

I was running my Spring-Boot application on JRE 14 in which this class appeared to be no longer available.

So once I changed my Spring-boot application (which hosts the REST-API) to use JRE 11 the error went away.

> Note: The pom.xml Java version attibute `<java.version>11</java.version>` needed to change as well as the JDK in the build path in Eclipse (which is the IDE I'm using) [JDK Buildpath](https://i.stack.imgur.com/THknM.png)

Comment: Good research.  Small note in case you haven't tried it yet, see whether you can update Spring Boot. On new Java versions, having up-to-date dependencies often fixes a problem.

Comment: Could there be another solution instead of downgrading Java?

Comment: I had the same issue trying to run apicurio-studio on JDK 15.  Downgrading to 11 worked.

Comment: I had the same issue and after I installed java 11, issue resolved.

Comment: Using keycloak 12.0.4 which is the latest version  and the facing this  issue.On java 11,8. Any idea whats going wrong?

Answer (score 17):

Ran into the same issue.

By the way, it's reported in the keycloak issue tracker here: https://issues.redhat.com/browse/KEYCLOAK-13690

Should be fixed in keycloak 11.

Comment: I was very pleased to see that Keycloak 11 was just released. Unfortunately they switched the FIX Version for this issue to Keycloak 12.

Comment: Update, they switched to fix it to Keycloak 13
https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/pull/7533

Comment: Keycloak 13 is out, I will try it out this week. We switched to Jetty for running under Java 15, hope that Tomcat will be working again with the new version.

Comment: Seems to be fixed in Java client artifacts of version `13.0.0`. It's now working under Tomcat and Java 15.

Answer (score 8):

I was able to get rid of this problem by keeping JDK 14 but switching from Tomcat to Jetty with Spring Boot. Jetty removed usage of this deprecated class `java.security.acl.Group` starting from 9.4.x. See here: https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/issues/3394. You have to be careful about choosing the right library version for `spring-boot-starter-jetty` to see if it is already using Jetty 9.4+ underneath.

This is how you switch from embedded Tomcat to Jetty:

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
      <exclusions>
        <!-- Exclude the Tomcat dependency -->
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Add Jetty as a replacement -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jetty</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried it, but the app is now failing with `org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'securityConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'keycloakConfigResolver'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'keycloakConfigResolver': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?`

Comment: Circular dependency is with my class `public class SecurityConfiguration extends KeycloakWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {`

Comment: FYI: I resolved the circular dependency by changing `@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = KeycloakSecurityComponents.class)` to `@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = KeycloakSpringBootConfigResolver.class)` on my `public class SecurityConfiguration extends KeycloakWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`.

Answer (score 2):

Check out latest adapter versions. This should be fixed with version >= 13.0

- Issue tracker: [KEYCLOAK-13633](https://issues.redhat.com/browse/KEYCLOAK-13633)
- [PR on GitHub](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/pull/7720)

Comment: I am getting the same error in Java 15 with Keycloak 15.0.2

Answer (score 0):

Just switch to jdk 1.8 for keycloak:legacy and it should work perfectly

Comment: even though this doesn't solve the problem. this is a temporary solution.  this worked for me. now no errors. keycloak works as expected

Answer (score 0):

In my case SpringBoot Application was using java 17 ,
2023-10-05 19:06:13.526  INFO 14332 --- [  restartedMain] com.souqh.SouqhbeApplication             : Starting SouqhbeApplication using Java 17.0.3 on ENCDAPPUNLT0210 with PID 14332 (F:\souqh\souqhbe\bin\main started by Ajinkya.Patil in F:\souqh\souqhbe)

I changed my installed JRE from 17 to 11 and it worked for me
You can follow below link to change installed JRE in eclipse
https://simply-how.com/getting-started-with-java-11#section-3