# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java/security/acl/Group When running spring security application

Tags: spring-security, keycloak

I am running `keycloak` from latest source code. When I am trying to run a spring boot application using this Keycloak i am getting following error:

```
2021-03-06 22:48:07.763  INFO 16931 --- [  restartedMain] eycloakSpringbootMicroserviceApplication : Starting KeycloakSpringbootMicroserviceApplication on manish with PID 16931 (/home/manish/Downloads/keycloak-springboot-microservice-master/target/classes started by manish in /home/manish/Downloads/keycloak-springboot-microservice-master)
2021-03-06 22:48:07.765  INFO 16931 --- [  restartedMain] eycloakSpringbootMicroserviceApplication : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2021-03-06 22:48:07.795  INFO 16931 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : Devtools property defaults active! Set 'spring.devtools.add-properties' to 'false' to disable
2021-03-06 22:48:07.795  INFO 16931 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : For additional web related logging consider setting the 'logging.level.web' property to 'DEBUG'
2021-03-06 22:48:08.613  INFO 16931 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8000 (http)
2021-03-06 22:48:08.619  INFO 16931 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2021-03-06 22:48:08.619  INFO 16931 --- [  restartedMain] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.33]
2021-03-06 22:48:08.666  INFO 16931 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2021-03-06 22:48:08.666  INFO 16931 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 871 ms
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.springframework.cglib.core.ReflectUtils (file:/home/manish/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-core/5.2.5.RELEASE/spring-core-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar) to method java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int,java.security.ProtectionDomain)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.springframework.cglib.core.ReflectUtils
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
2021-03-06 22:48:08.856  INFO 16931 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Creating filter chain: any request, [org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@652b46d, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@130d5b36, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@6ad0fc97, org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.filter.KeycloakPreAuthActionsFilter@4c999787, org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.filter.KeycloakAuthenticationProcessingFilter@119a8166, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@1685ff5e, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@215e0854, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@2b5a9df2, org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.filter.KeycloakSecurityContextRequestFilter@31f052ce, org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.filter.KeycloakAuthenticatedActionsFilter@31d5ced8, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@36ec039e, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@372c7841, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@3d40d543, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@1e86a670]
2021-03-06 22:48:08.933  INFO 16931 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2021-03-06 22:48:09.051  INFO 16931 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.a.OptionalLiveReloadServer       : LiveReload server is running on port 35729
2021-03-06 22:48:09.078  INFO 16931 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8000 (http) with context path ''
2021-03-06 22:48:09.081  INFO 16931 --- [  restartedMain] eycloakSpringbootMicroserviceApplication : Started KeycloakSpringbootMicroserviceApplication in 1.623 seconds (JVM running for 2.19)
2021-03-06 22:48:27.540 ERROR 16931 --- [nio-8000-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost]           : Exception Processing /

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java/security/acl/Group
    at org.keycloak.adapters.tomcat.KeycloakAuthenticatorValve.createPrincipalFactory(KeycloakAuthenticatorValve.java:96) ~[spring-boot-container-bundle-9.0.2.jar:9.0.2]
    at org.keycloak.adapters.tomcat.AbstractKeycloakAuthenticatorValve.createSessionTokenStore(AbstractKeycloakAuthenticatorValve.java:262) ~[spring-boot-container-bundle-9.0.2.jar:9.0.2]
    at org.keycloak.adapters.tomcat.AbstractKeycloakAuthenticatorValve.getTokenStore(AbstractKeycloakAuthenticatorValve.java:251) ~[spring-boot-container-bundle-9.0.2.jar:9.0.2]
    at org.keycloak.adapters.tomcat.KeycloakAuthenticatorValve.getTokenStore(KeycloakAuthenticatorValve.java:106) ~[spring-boot-container-bundle-9.0.2.jar:9.0.2]
    at org.keycloak.adapters.tomcat.AbstractKeycloakAuthenticatorValve.checkKeycloakSession(AbstractKeycloakAuthenticatorValve.java:228) ~[spring-boot-container-bundle-9.0.2.jar:9.0.2]
    at org.keycloak.adapters.tomcat.AbstractKeycloakAuthenticatorValve.invoke(AbstractKeycloakAuthenticatorValve.java:180) ~[spring-boot-container-bundle-9.0.2.jar:9.0.2]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:373) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1594) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832) ~[na:na]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: java.security.acl.Group
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:606) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:168) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522) ~[na:na]
    ... 19 common frames omitted

2021-03-06 22:48:27.547  INFO 16931 --- [nio-8000-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2021-03-06 22:48:27.547  INFO 16931 --- [nio-8000-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2021-03-06 22:48:27.551  INFO 16931 --- [nio-8000-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 4 ms
```

`pom.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.6.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.dinuth</groupId>
    <artifactId>keycloak-springboot-microservice</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>keycloak-springboot-microservice</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot Keycloak Integration</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <keycloak.version>9.0.2</keycloak.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
            <artifactId>keycloak-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>${keycloak.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.keycloak.bom</groupId>
                <artifactId>keycloak-adapter-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${keycloak.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

`Java`

java --version

openjdk 11.0.9.1 2020-11-04
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.9.1+1-Ubuntu-0ubuntu1.18.04)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.9.1+1-Ubuntu-0ubuntu1.18.04, mixed mode, sharing)

Comment: Which java version do you use?

Comment: openjdk 11.0.9.1 2020-11-04 OpenJDK Runtime Environment

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Keycloak java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java/security/acl/Group using Springboot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62646999/keycloak-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-java-security-acl-group-using-springboo)

Comment: My command line show Open JDK 11

Comment: any reason to why you are using such an old keycloak starter? https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.keycloak/keycloak-spring-boot-starter

Comment: I also have this error and I'm using `12.0.4`

Comment: Use Spring boot version 2.5.0 with keycloak version 13.0.0