# KeyCloak Server Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: java.security.acl.Group with java 11

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, keycloak

I am trying to secure my spring application with keycloak and when I invoke the REST API I get the following error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: java.security.acl.Group
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:606) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:168) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522) ~[na:na]
    ... 19 common frames omitted
```

I found another post with the same problem ([KeyCloak Server Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: java.security.acl.Group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61932188/keycloak-server-caused-by-java-lang-classnotfoundexception-java-security-acl-g)) and it was solved using Java 11, but I already used it and I'm still getting the same error.

Any idea about how to solve it?

I am using the KC 12.0.4, the config is exported here:
https://github.com/aleon91/keycloak/blob/main/realm-export.json

The Spring Security config is here:
https://github.com/aleon91/keycloak/blob/main/src/main/java/com/leonlyon/auth/config/KeycloakSecurityConfig.java

And the pom.xml here:
https://github.com/aleon91/keycloak/blob/main/pom.xml

Comment: What version of KC do you use?

Comment: Can you provide you application config ( KC part ) ,your spring security config and your pom.xml ( KC part) ?