# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java/security/acl/Group from Keycloak

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat, keycloak

This is actually duplicate for this question: [KeyCloak Server Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: java.security.acl.Group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61932188/keycloak-server-caused-by-java-lang-classnotfoundexception-java-security-acl-g)

I cannot possibly downgrade my JDK or use jetty. So is there a way to force keycloak use java.security.Policy instead of java.security.acl.Group?

```
2021-07-15 12:44:40,714 [35m[http-nio-7008-exec-3][0;39m TRACE-ID=[] X-CLIENT-ID=[] [1;31mERROR[0;39m o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost]#175 - Exception Processing /admin-bff/v1/accounts/3014/products/42/callback
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java/security/acl/Group
    at org.keycloak.adapters.tomcat.KeycloakAuthenticatorValve.createPrincipalFactory(KeycloakAuthenticatorValve.java:96)
    at org.keycloak.adapters.tomcat.AbstractKeycloakAuthenticatorValve.createSessionTokenStore(AbstractKeycloakAuthenticatorValve.java:262)
    at org.keycloak.adapters.tomcat.AbstractKeycloakAuthenticatorValve.getTokenStore(AbstractKeycloakAuthenticatorValve.java:251)
    at org.keycloak.adapters.tomcat.KeycloakAuthenticatorValve.getTokenStore(KeycloakAuthenticatorValve.java:106)
    at org.keycloak.adapters.tomcat.AbstractKeycloakAuthenticatorValve.checkKeycloakSession(AbstractKeycloakAuthenticatorValve.java:228)
    at org.keycloak.adapters.tomcat.AbstractKeycloakAuthenticatorValve.invoke(AbstractKeycloakAuthenticatorValve.java:180)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:373)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1590)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: java.security.acl.Group
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:606)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:168)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
    ... 19 common frames omitted
```

Comment: I think this should be fixed with version >= 13.0. Which version of the Keycloak adapter do you use?

Comment: @sventorben keycloak 9.0.2 and JDK 11

Comment: @sventorben upgrading to keycloak 13.0.0 or hiegher actually works

Comment: I am getting same error in JDK 15.0  and keycloak 15.0.2

Answer (score 1):

I think this should be fixed with version >= 13.0:

- [KEYCLOAK-13633](https://issues.redhat.com/browse/KEYCLOAK-13633)
- [PR on GitHub](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/pull/7720)

Try to upgrade your Keycloak adapter to at least version 13.0.