# JackRabbit Server Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: java.security.acl.Group on Java 17

Tags: java, jcr, jackrabbit

I'm using JackRabbit 2.20.6 for storing multimedia files ( pictures ), and I'm getting the following error during execution:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java/security/acl/Group

    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1012)
    at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:150)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:862)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassOnClassPathOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:760)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:681)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:639)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.security.simple.SimpleSecurityManager$SimplePrincipalProvider.<init>(SimpleSecurityManager.java:321)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.security.simple.SimpleSecurityManager$SimplePrincipalProvider.<init>(SimpleSecurityManager.java:309)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.security.simple.SimpleSecurityManager.init(SimpleSecurityManager.java:169)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.RepositoryImpl.getSecurityManager(RepositoryImpl.java:483)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.RepositoryImpl.login(RepositoryImpl.java:1496)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.commons.AbstractRepository.login(AbstractRepository.java:123)
    at org.gs4tr.foundation.modules.repository.jack.jcr.CustomJcrTemplate.execute(CustomJcrTemplate.java:38)
    at org.gs4tr.foundation.modules.repository.jack.JackRabbitRepositoryManagerImpl.store(JackRabbitRepositoryManagerImpl.java:373)
```

Can someone help me for fixing this?

Note: I'm using Java 17.

Comment: This class was removed from the JRE, so you either have to downgrade the JRE for this project or check/wait for a newer version of JackRabbit that fixes this problem. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61932188/keycloak-server-caused-by-java-lang-classnotfoundexception-java-security-acl-g and https://www.mail-archive.com/dev@jackrabbit.apache.org/msg44403.html

Answer (score 1):

2.20.* should not require acl.group; see https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/JCR-4467.

The simplest possible explanation is that you have old JAR files in your classpath.